# Error occurrs while processing this directive PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that contains an album of photos. Each photo has a checkbox. When the user presses submit, the checked boxes are sent to another page for processing. So far this works fine for most albums, even up to 100 photo, but there is one album that has 262 photos.

If a user tries to submit that form, the error: `an error occurred while processing this directive` shows up. Any clue what may be causing this and why it only happens with larger albums?

Comment: Turn on error printing in the PHP configuration if you want to see more specific error messages.

Comment: I turned on error printing, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://robzu.com/sscce-short-self-contained-correct-compilable-example)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you reach the maximum POST size or the GET size?

The 1st one is an option in your php.ini, the 2nd one [is a limit in the size of an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/208623).